# asp.net c# vs2017 javascript Eval passing parameter problem

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, eval

I am developing a C# ASP.NET Visual Studio 2017 project. I have a problem which gives no error, just does not work. I have image button which is needed to act as hyperlink when clicked.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="96px" Width="458px"  OnClientClick='<%#  "javascript:windowOpen("+ Eval("HYPERLINK")+ ");" %>' />
```

when it is clicked it calls JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function windowOpen(hyperlink) {
        myWindow=window.open(hyperlink,'_blank','width=200,height=100, scrollbars=no,resizable=no')
    
        myWindow.focus()
            }
</script>
```

however when it is clicked the page is refresing itself, no error and no expected result

Answer (score 0):

did you try removing the `runat = "server"` attribute and see if its working as you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="96px" Width="458px" AutoPostback="false"  OnClientClick='<%#  "javascript:return windowOpen("+ Eval("HYPERLINK")+ ");" %>' />

function windowOpen(hyperlink) {
var myWindowl;
myWindow=window.open(hyperlink,'_blank','width=200,height=100, scrollbars=no,resizable=no')
myWindow.focus();
return false;
}